# Adding an icon to a html i tag

Tags: jquery, icons, addclass

In jQuery, how can I add an icon to an `i` tag?

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="example_infobox1">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon"><i class=""></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
                <span class="info-box-text">Messages</span>
                <span class="info-box-number">1,410</span>
            </div>
            <!-- /.info-box-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.info-box -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
</div>
```

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
$('.example_infobox4 .i').addClass('fa fa-envelope-o');
```

Can I please have some help with this?

Thanks

Comment: `$('.info-box-icon i')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You selector is wrong. `.i` will find the element having class `i`. `i` will find the element by tag.

```
$('.example_infobox4 i').addClass('fa fa-envelope-o');
```

**OR**

More specific:

```
$('.info-box-icon i').addClass('fa fa-envelope-o');
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/nfjuk7mq/

Answer (score 0):

`<i></i>` is an element in HTML and not a class. CSS selector for elements in html is `element` itself. i.e. if you have the following html, this is how you would select `<i></i>`

```
    <div class="division">
        <i class=""></i>
    </div>
```

`$(".division i").addClass("fa fa-envelop-o");`

Visit this link for more details - [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

> **Find you I tag and apply your class**

```
$('body').find('i').addClass('customeClass')
```

see this example:http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/8vvubj1k/

> Hear I don't now your parent div so I use body in find so instead of
>   body use your parent selecter

**Or as per your example use this selector**

```
$('.example_infobox1').find('i').addClass('fa fa-envelope-o')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Script

```
var i = document.getElementsByTagName("i");
i.setAttribute("class", "class name");
i.setAttribute("src", "icon link");
```